# Unauthorized 401 - Spring Boot service

Tags: spring-boot, docker, http

I have a spring boot service calling another spring boot service.

Both services deployed into docker container.

And when the first service calling the second service, the second service got 401 response. While when i do the same request using PostMan I got a valid response.

Given I am using the credential through postman and the service itself.

Any Idea why this may happen? Is there any related to docker deployment ?

Code used to call the second service

```
try {
        urlStr = licenseRequest.getString(LicenseRequest.URL);
        logger.info("URL: "+ urlStr);
        
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        // auth 
        String authStrEncoded = Base64Utils.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStrEncoded);
        
        if (!licenseRequest.isNull(LicenseRequest.BODY))
        {
            String body = licenseRequest.getString(LicenseRequest.BODY);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                con.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(body.getBytes());
            wr.close();
        }
            //Get Response  
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(line);
              response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        
    }
```

Comment: Does the Authorization header look the same in postman request as in service? if you receive 401 it means that the server can communicate with the other server is not docker related, it is related to the auth

Comment: Yes, The Authorization header is exactly the same